# How do I use Ruby in an HTML document

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following HTML in my index file.

```
<% @posts.each_with_index do |post, index| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= index+1 %></td>
    <td><%= post.team_elo %></td>
    <td><%= post.team_name %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

I have a function called `is_eligible` which takes `post.team_name` as an argument. I want to run it each "do iteration" and skip all three printing steps if it returns false

I'm not sure how to

1. include the file is_eligible is in and
2. structure the code within the html somewhere.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
# The view
<% @posts.each_with_index do |post, index| %>
  <% unless post.is_eligible? %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= index+1 %></td>
      <td><%= post.team_elo %></td>
      <td><%= post.team_name %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
<% end %>

# The model post.rb
def is_eligible?
  # and there you use self.name to access the name
end
```

Comment: Thomas, this looks like it should be working to me. I removed the argument to is_eligible? and made is_eligible? a part of post.rb. I'm also now using self.name to access, as you suggested. But I still get: undefined method 'is_eligible?' for nil:NilClass.

Comment: I got it working. Thanks Thomas. Didn't need the @ in @post.is_eligible.

Comment: Oh yeah sorry, mistake from me. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
<% @posts.select{|p| is_eligible(p. team_name)}.each_with_index do |post, index| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= index+1 %></td>
    <td><%= post.team_elo %></td>
    <td><%= post.team_name %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```